# Google Finance in python pandas_reader - How to prevent Google blocking the access?

Tags: python, pandas, google-finance-api, pandas-datareader

When using the python `pandas_datareader` to retrieve stock data, Google once in a while blocks the access when too many requests are sent in a certain time frame.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as web
df = web.DataReader(name=ticker, data_source='google', start='20170421', end='20170421')
```

Imagine that I have to iterate through several of such tickers ('AAPL','MSFT',....). Does anyone know how many requests per second/minute/hour/day can be sent without running into issues with Google?

Comment: I think that's using the now deprecated Google Finance API (https://developers.google.com/finance/) so the documentation on rate limits is no longer available. More importantly, that code is going to break pretty soon when Google finally shuts down the API so you might want to use something else anyway.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I am already using alternate sources. This is just a backup for verification purposes.